# Change Cursor to another window on BufWritePost in Vim

Tags: windows, vim, split

I have a function that whenever it is called it splits the window and displays some information, placing the cursor in this new window.

So far so good.

But I am implementing an `autocommand` that will trigger the same function, and everything works great except that the cursor never changes to the opened window like when it is not running with the autocommand.

The line that triggers this looks like:

```
 autocmd! BufWritePost *.py call MyFunction()
```

Like I said, it works great when you call manually `:call MyFunction()` but not with the autocommand.

I think Bram mentioned that autocommands are really not meant to split windows or even move the cursor.

Is there any way around this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `<Ctrl-w><Ctrl-j><CR>` or whatever movement you want to the function?

Comment: yes, I've tried that and I've tried also with WindowNumber . 'wincmd w' and `wincmd p`. To no avail.

Comment: Looks like cursor normally changes inside an autocommand, but its position is restored after event is finished. Maybe you should just not close window with information when it is left?

Comment: A longshot, but maybe stuffing keystrokes using feedkeys() would work around the problem of returning to original window after the autocommand? See `:h feedkeys`.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz. This do work, though you have to duplicate all feedkeys calls with `wincmd` commands as feedkeys starts working only after autocommand finished. I guess you should write this as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by what ZyX said in the comments to original question, it sounds like this would work:

```
function MyFunction()
    [ have all commands you currently have]
    [ . . . ]

    " then as last line include call to feedkeys()
    " this will stuff keystrokes into key buffer
    " and get executed after MyFunction() ends
    " remember that location will always be in 
    " original window, i.e, window that vim
    " was in when autocommand was triggered
    " so if new window is below original
    " window you could use this:

    " feedkeys call below edited to reflect ZyX's
    " improvement of \<C-\>\<C-n> to guarantee
    " we're in Normal mode before using window
    " movement key combo

    call feedkeys("\<C-\>\<C-n>\<c-w>j", 'n')

endfunction
```

Comment: I guess you missed `, "n"` in `feedkeys()` call. Don't rely on user not remapped `<C-w>`.

Comment: @ZyX -- Yes, you're right, should have `n` flag.  Edited to add that.

Comment: @alfredodeza. I suggest not to change `Nwincmd w` in section before feedkeys, but after `\<C-w>j` is slightly less keys to type.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz: By the way `<C-w>j` works fine as well. `<C-w><C-j>` variant was only defined to avoid fast typing errors: when you press j before you manage to remove finger from control.

Comment: There is a caveat though: after BufWritePost event you may end up not in normal mode. You can of course write `\<C-\>\<C-n>` before `\<C-w>` but guess switching mode is worse in this case (example is saving with mapping to `<C-o>:w<CR>`). I cannot suggest anything to fix this issue now.

Comment: @ZyX -- I'm not following what the issue with `<c-\><c-N>` is.  Will `<c-\><c-N>` not work to restore normal mode with a <c-O> write operation from insert mode?

Comment: @Herbert Sitz. It will produce mode error. I mean that after autocommand is launched and `<C-\><C-n>` was fed user will think he is still in insert mode, but he won't be. Looks like I am seeing a problem where it is not: we are going to switch to other window, so the sentence about «mode error» is not applicable as switching itself will produce such error unless is expected.